# Running Web Server from Andoird Phone

Tags: networking, router, firewall, android, iptables

Problem - Trying to run Tiny Web Server on Android Phone. Internally I'm able to access the server home page from all devices connected to hotspot including Gateway.

Hotspot Gateway - 192.168.43.1 (Android/LYF-LS4503/Rooted/4G-LTE)

ifconfig output on Gateway Phone, rmnet_data0 (Public Interface??) shows IPv4 10.n.n.n which is not same as the IP being displayed onto pages like whatsmyip.org .Some other interfaces shows IPv6 addresses but I don't know what they are for?

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Thanks